# Fetching hindi text from database mysql

Tags: mysql, database

i am saving the hindi text into the database. It is saving in db as "हिन्डि".

But while fetching i am not able to fetch the same hindi text instead it is fetching the above mentioned uniciode characters

Comment: show the code: table structure and SQL, where you are saving and fetching. Are you using any programming language?

Answer (score 0):

First check for UTF8 compatibility with below query. If it supports you should see the output as “Character_set_system”| “UTF8″

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE ‘character_set_system’;
```

if its not run below query to change it

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable MODIFY text VARCHAR(200) CHARACTER SET UTF8;
```

Then execute following query before inserting into the table:

```
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');        
mysql_query('SET names=utf8');        
mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');        
mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
mysql_query('SET collation_connection=utf8_general_ci');
```